# UserManager.FindAsync not working with custom implementation of UserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity-2

I am relatively new in ASP.NET Identity. To understand the things better I am doing a custom implementation of ASP.NET Identity. I am able to create user successfully using the custom code. However the `FindAsync(username, password)` functionality is not working.

Here is what I have done so far:

**User**: This is my `User` class that inherits from `IUser<int>`

```
public class User:IUser<int>
{
    public User(){ Id = 0; }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
}
```

**UserStore**: This is custom implementation of `IUserStore' and 'IUserPasswordStore`

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<User, int>, IUserPasswordStore<User, int>
{
    private IdentityContext _context;
    public UserStore()
    {
        _context = new IdentityContext();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #region IUserStore<T,K> members
    public Task CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        _context.Users.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
    {
        return _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(user=>user.Id==userId);
    }

    public Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName.Equals(userName));
        return user;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IUserPasswordStore<User,int>
    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash)
    {
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(User user)
    {
        return new Task<string>(() => user.PasswordHash);
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(User user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In my MVC5 controller I have the following line that tries find the user by username and password:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync("User1355436", "passw0rd");
```

The above line of code in turn sequentially invokes the following methods of `UserStore`:

`public Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName)` and 
`public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(User user)`.

And after that the code goes to waiting state perpetually and nothing happens, i.e. the control is never returned to the controller again.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Hello I want to understand how Web api call from other application of mvc how it will work please give me any github or your application demo link where I can see.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is likely with this line of code...

```
return new Task<string>(() => user.PasswordHash);
```

... this creates a task that is never started, so the code waiting for its continuation waits forever. For returning a value wrapped in a task, use `Task.FromResult()`...

```
return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash);
```

Comment: Now I know what happend in the last 10 hours of debugging, +1 for finishing my pain. But why in hell we return a `Task` and the calling class do not start it?!